# user is redirected to logout->login on new tab opening (nextjs)

Tags: reactjs, redirect, cookies, next.js, frontend

my system has a 2 token authentication configuration - 12 hour `refreshToken` and a 5 min `accessToken`. these tokens are saved in `Cookies`.
every request made to the backend has to present the `accessToken`, if it is expired or missing, the system asks for a new one using the `refreshToken` and saves the new `accessToken`.
if the `refreshToken` is missing, or if the `accessToken` returned from the backend is `undefined` [which indicates that the `refreshToken` has expired] - the system redirects the user back to the logout page [which houses only a `useEffect` to clear the cookies] and then back to login.

for some reason, after login, if a user opens a new tab [either a duplicate or jsut another page in the site] they are being redirected to logout->login, and the cookies are cleared from both tabs.

**EDIT**

For some reason, on opening the duplicate tab, no request goes out to the server, i.e. - `getServerSideProps()` is not called yet there is a redirect to logout.
also - this issue is replicated on Chrome and FireFox on mac, but not on Safari or Chrome on windows.
On browsers it is occurring on it also happens on opening a new tab and copying the url to it.

**Obtain `RefreshToken`**

```
const auth = async ({ body, res }) => {
    try {
        const url = `obtainRefreshTokenEndpoint`;
        const { refresh: token } = await fetch({ url, body });
        res.setHeader(
            'set-cookie',
            `refreshToken=${token}; HttpOnly; Path=/; Max-Age=86000`
        );
        return { token, error: undefined };
    } catch (error) {
        return { token: undefined, error };
    }
};
```

**Get/Refresh the `accessToken`**

```
const refreshToken = async (refresh, res) => {
    try {
        const url = `/refreshTokenEndpoint`;
        const body = { refresh };
        const access = await fetch({ url, body });

        res.setHeader(
            'set-cookie',
            `access=${access.access}; HttpOnly; Path=/; Max-Age=86000`
        );
        return { access };
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error(e);
        return e;
    }
};
```

**Redirect to logout page if anything goes wrong**

```
const redirectToLogout = (res) => {
    return res.writeHead(308, { Location: '/logout' }).end();
};
```

Comment: Where is `auth` and `refreshToken` being called from? Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

**Duplicate tab behaviour for after redirect for nextJs (getServerSideProps)**

When you duplicate a tab, the getServerSideProps function will not run again because it runs on the server side during the initial request.

When you duplicate a tab, the browser creates a new instance of the existing tab, including the current state and content. The duplicated tab doesn't send a new request to the server, so the server-side rendering process, including the execution of getServerSideProps, doesn't occur.

Instead, the duplicated tab will load the existing page content from its local cache or session. This behaviour is determined by the browser and can vary across different browsers.

If you need to handle specific behaviour when a user duplicates a tab, you may consider implementing client-side checks or using other techniques such as WebSocket or polling to synchronise session state or perform additional actions on the client side.

Solution:

To prevent this behaviour I found one better solution for it to prevent cache control of redirect response for all browsers (ctx.res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store')). Now the issue will be completely resolved for duplicating the tab.

```
    /* 
        ctx.res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store') sets the Cache-Control header to 'no-store', 
        indicating that the response should not be stored or cached.
        By setting the cache control header in this way, you can prevent caching of the redirect response.
        Issue resolved: duplicate tab redirected to cache route
    */
    ctx.res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store');
    return {
        redirect: {
            permanent: false,
            destination: '/logout',
        },
     }
```